# How to resolve "Undefined variable" in a PHP program?

Tags: php, mysqli

A kind Stack Overflow member gave me some help in regards to converting an unsafe query to one which uses parameters, but I am struggling to get it to work. I could have kept bothering him but the original question was unrelated. So I posted a new one!

```
<?php


$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database");// connection
$key = $_POST['key'];
$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM handover  WHERE hs LIKE ? OR WHERE nv    

LIKE ? OR WHERE vsa LIKE ?"); 
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $key, $key, $key); 
$stmt->execute();
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count==0 ){

echo "</br></br></br></br></br></br></br><h2>Handover Details</h2><p>  No results    

found</p>";
}
else{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

These are my errors:
```

I am getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: stmt in E:\NEW1\xampp\htdocs\FINTAN\keyword.php on line 112
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in E:\NEW1\xampp\htdocs\FINTAN\keyword.php on line 112

```
<?php


$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test3");// connection
$key = $_POST['key'];
$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM handover WHERE hs LIKE ? OR nv LIKE ? OR vsa 

LIKE    ?"); 
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $key, $key, $key); 
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$rows = $stmt->num_rows;

if($rows==0 ){

echo "</br></br></br></br></br></br></br><h2>Handover Details</h2>

<p> WORKING none    

found</p>";
}
else{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

Comment: Look at my answer,replace those $stmt with $query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM handover  WHERE hs LIKE ? OR nv    
LIKE ? OR vsa LIKE ?"
```

Remove the extra WHEREs,also you need

```
$query->bind_param("sss", $key, $key, $key); 
$query->execute();

$query->store_result();
$rows = $query->num_rows;

if($rows==0 )
```

Comment: hello i tried that still getting same errors. Its the stmt variable i think. it says undefined but that is where i asign to it?